# DFA to represent a password

Tags: computation-theory, dfa

I want to design a DFA for a password that has following constraints:

- it must be 8 characters long
- it must contain at least two lowercase characters: `[a-z]`
- it must contain at least one uppercase characters: `[A-Z]`
- it must contain at least two decimal numbers: `[0-9]`
- it must contain at least one of these special characters: `[!.@*_]`
- it must begin with a special character

How do I design this DFA?

Comment: This is going to be a *very* large DFA...

Comment: That's the point, is there any way to minimize it ?

Answer (score 3):

Any DFA for this language will need to remember at least

- how many lower-case letters have been read (0, 1, or 2 or more),
- how many upper-case letters have been read (0, or 1 or more), and
- how many decimal digits have been read (0, 1, or 2 or more).

That gives you a minimum of at least 18 states, and that doesn't even factor in the length restrictions. I don't think you're going to find a simple DFA for this language. It's just going to be big.

Now, you can construct a DFA that's rather straightforward but huge by building one DFA for each restriction (none of these are too bad) and then doing a many-way product construction to construct a DFA for the overall language. I think this is the most theoretically elegant way to do this and it's actually pretty easy to represent this in software. If I had to actually build the DFA, this is how I'd do it.